Compose VerticalPager nested in scrollable Column. Column scroll physics got lost
When there's only one page in the pager (or pager at the last page), the finger move on pager results Column to scroll. And this is the desired behaviour. The problem is, in this case scroll loses its physics/momentum. e.g. scroll stops at the moment user remove finger from the screen. Can't find the solution.
@Composable
fun NestedViewPager() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { 1 })
        VerticalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(400.dp),
        ) { page ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(color = Color.Blue)) {
                Text(text = "Page $page")
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(700.dp))
    }
}


I would recommend that you open up an issue on the Google Issue Tracker and paste the exact code you have here there: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues

What's missing is fling gesture which is consumed in postFling of VerticalPager. By using a NestedScrollDispatcher as parameter of Modifier.nestedScrollConnection you can trigger fling or scroll gestures on parent.
val nestedScrollDispatcher = remember {
    NestedScrollDispatcher()
}

val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { 1 })



 val pagerNestedScrollConnection = remember {
    object : NestedScrollConnection {

        override suspend fun onPreFling(available: Velocity): Velocity {
            if ((!pagerState.canScrollForward && available.y < 0) || (!pagerState.canScrollBackward && available.y > 0)) {
                nestedScrollDispatcher.dispatchPostFling(Velocity.Zero, available)
            }
            return super.onPreFling(available)
        }
    }
}

And apply Modifier
    VerticalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(400.dp)
            .nestedScroll(pagerNestedScrollConnection, nestedScrollDispatcher)


NestedScroll can be used in 2 ways. One is to get preScroll or preFling gestures and use them to create a logic such as collapsingToolbar or passing these gestures or cancel child interactions. Second one is using it in a child and scrolling or having fling gestures on parent when used with NestedScrollDispatcher.

Sure, what i meant by this answer is correct animation is fling and you can force parent to have fling gesture by using NestedScrollDispatcher and dispatching fling gesture. NestedScrollDispatcher is something is not known widely but it can force parent to invoke gestures based on child's behavior.

Using this solution if there's more than 1 page, then just after I swiped to the last page, the parent scrolls, e.g. scroll triggers twiсe. I was able to make it work using PerFling though onPreFling(available: Velocity): Velocity, by dispatching pre fling to post fling if conditions met: nestedScrollDispatcher.dispatchPostFling(Velocity.Zero, available) and return Velocity.Zero.  If conditions not met, then return super.onPreFling(available)

Sure, i updated it to use in preFling but i don't think returning Velocity.Zero is necessary because super.onPreFling(available) is already Velocity.Zero.

I was able to achieve somewhat acceptable by using NestedScrollConnection. Here is the workaround
@Composable
fun NestedViewPager() {
    val parentScrollState = rememberScrollState()
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().verticalScroll(parentScrollState)
    ) {
        val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { 1 })
        VerticalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(400.dp)
                .nestedScroll(connection = object : NestedScrollConnection {
                    override suspend fun onPreFling(available: Velocity): Velocity {
                        if (!pagerState.canScrollForward && available.y < 0) {
                            parentScrollState.animateScrollTo(
                                value = parentScrollState.value + (available.y * -0.14f).toInt(),
                                animationSpec = tween(500, easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing)
                            )
                            return Velocity.Zero
                        }
                        if (!pagerState.canScrollBackward && available.y > 0) {
                            parentScrollState.animateScrollTo(
                                value = parentScrollState.value - (available.y * 0.14f).toInt(),
                                animationSpec = tween(500, easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing)
                            )
                            return Velocity.Zero
                        }
                        return super.onPreFling(available)
                    }
                })
        ) { page ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(color = Color.Blue)) {
                Text(text = "Page $page")
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(700.dp))
    }
}

The multiplier 0.14f, duration 500 and animationSpec are just values that I found pleasing enough and providing similar to native scroll effect.
